# Contour plot masked on the basis of grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a contour plot based on **(x,y)** coordinates surface with a cube in it that dosent include any data **z** . Following is its scatterplot.

[image: scatterplot]

I use the following code to generate a mesh and interpolate data to plot such a contour map. I try to mask the interpolated data **Zi** but it still gives me an unmasked contour plot. I also tried to mask x and y coordinates but that dosent do any good.

```
x = centre_unadj['X [mm]']
y = centre_unadj['Y [mm]']
z = centre_unadj['LDA1-RMS [m/s]']

plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(20, 15), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
xi,yi = np.meshgrid(x,y)
mask =(yi> 0) & (yi< 25) & (xi > -53) & (xi < -25) 
#mask_xi = (xi > -53) & (xi < -25) 
#mask_yi = (yi> 0) & (yi< 25)
#yi = ma.masked_array(yi,mask =(yi> 0) & (yi< 25) )
#xi = ma.masked_array(xi,mask=((xi > -53) & (xi < -25) ))
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x,y), z, (xi, yi) , method='cubic')
zi = ma.masked_array(zi, mask = ((yi> 0) & (yi< 25) & (xi > -53) & (xi < -25)) )

#zi[mask]=np.nan

plt.contourf( xi,yi,zi,100)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This is the plot I get after running the above code.

[image: colorbar plot]

I just dont want any contour interpolation inside the cubic area where there are no datapoints.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. How are we supposed to know, what `centre_unadj` is?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am just looking for some techniques I am missing out on or a stupid mistake that others can point out. So I didnt feel any need for a reproducible example.

Comment: The first plot shows `x=centre_unadj['X [mm]']` vs `y=centre_unadj['Y [mm]']` right?

Comment: Yes , that is correct . It represents a grid where a square is missing.

Comment: I think what I propesed will solve your problem. In the future however it would be really good practice to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, in order to make sure that whoever wants to answer will be able to reproduce (and therefore solve) the __same__ problem you have, instead of an answerer defined version trying to guess your data

Comment: You're right , I will make sure to give such examples in my next post . It seems like you had to put in a lot of work to solve this due to my shortcomings, I am sorry about that. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the meshgrid generation. The values in `y` go from 0 to 40 more than a dozen times. Thus, the generated `xi` and `yi` will be really unintuitive matrixes.

The proper way of generating the meshgrid is the following:

```
xi,yi = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),200),np.linspace(y.min(),y.max(),200))
```

### Example

I have generated some data with a similar shape:

```
import scipy.signal as sgn
import scipy.interpolate as intr
import numpy.ma as ma
x = np.linspace(-100,0,500)
y = sgn.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * .2 * x)
mask = (x>-50) & (x<-25)
y[mask] = (sgn.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * .2 * x[mask])+1)/2
y = (y+1)*25
plt.plot(x,y)
z = np.sin(2*np.pi*.1*x)+np.sin(2*np.pi*.1*y)
```

Such that the plot x vs y looks like:

[image: sawtooth]

The code you are actually using generates the following plot:

```
xi,yi = np.meshgrid(x,y)
mask =(yi> 0) & (yi< 25) & (xi > -53) & (xi < -25) 
zi = intr.griddata((x,y), z, (xi, yi) , method='cubic')
zi = ma.masked_array(zi, mask = mask )
plt.contourf( xi,yi,zi,100); plt.colorbar()
```

[image: bad contourf]

The interpolation to obtain the grid data yields unexpected and incorrect results, which result in the obtained `contourf`. In fact, plotting `plt.imshow(mask)` reveals the positions in the matrix where the values inside the square `(y > 0) & (y < 25) & (x > -53) & (x < -25)` are placed in the matrix.

[image: mask imshow]

When the meshgrid is defined as proposed, the result is this one instead:

[image]