# Mask values inside given path (triangle, square etc) for a contourf plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to mask specific locations (triangles, squares) for a contourf plot. I can do the mask based on the Z values but finding it difficult to get it work based on x and y values. For the MWE below, I want to create a mask between given X,Y values (triangle or square). Lets say for the example below, I want to mask values inside triangle formed between points (0,0),(2,0),(0,2). I want to basically be able to provide an enclosed path and mask everything in between those values. I have tried the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863060/contour-plot-masked-on-the-basis-of-grid) but I have to provide the logic for individual X and Y values which becomes cumbersome for a complicated path.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

origin = 'lower'

delta = 0.025

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

  
fig1, ax2 = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
CS = ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, 10, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, origin=origin,extend='both')

  
ax2.set_title('Random Plot')
ax2.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
cbar = fig1.colorbar(CS)
```

[image: Example contourf plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convex shape such as a triangle can be defined by the equations of the lines going through their vertices.  In this case the equations are quite simple: `X >= 0` is the zone right of the line through `0,0` and `0,2`. Similar `Y >= 0` and `X + Y <= 2` are the two other zones. The triangle is the intersection of these 3 zones.

Setting the corresponding `Z` values to `NaN` will create the empty triangle in the contour plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X ** 2 - Y ** 2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1) ** 2 - (Y - 1) ** 2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

Z[(X >= 0) & (Y >= 0) & (X + Y <= 2)] = np.nan

fig1, ax2 = plt.subplots()
CS = ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, 10, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, origin='lower', extend='both')

ax2.set_title('Random Plot missing a triangle')
ax2.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
cbar = fig1.colorbar(CS)

plt.show()
```

[image: contour plot with triangular hole]

PS: The equation of a line through two points `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` is

```
(X - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (Y - y1) * (x2 - x1) == 0
```

So, a more general code could look like:

```
def line_eq(X, Y, p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    return (X - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (Y - y1) * (x2 - x1) >= 0

p = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0)] # clockwise ordering
Z[line_eq(X, Y, p[0], p[1]) & line_eq(X, Y, p[1], p[2]) & line_eq(X, Y, p[2], p[0])] = np.nan
```

Note that when the vertices are ordered counterclockwise, the equation should be `<= 0` to grab the interior convex shape.

Concave shapes can be created by taking the union (logical `or`) of several convex shapes:

```py
def line_eq(X, Y, p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    return (X - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (Y - y1) * (x2 - x1) >= 0

def convex_eq(X, Y, p):
    mask = line_eq(X, Y, p[-1], p[0])
    for p1, p2 in zip(p[:-1], p[1:]):
        mask &= line_eq(X, Y, p1, p2)
    return mask

def multiple_convex_eq(X, Y, c):
    mask = convex_eq(X, Y, c[0])
    for ci in c:
        mask |= convex_eq(X, Y, ci)
    return mask

p = [(0, 2.5), (1.5, 1), (1, -2), (-1, -2), (-1.5, 1)]  # pentagon, clockwise ordering
five_trianggles = [[(0, 0), p1, p2] for p1, p2 in zip(p, (p + p)[2:])]
Z[multiple_convex_eq(X, Y, five_trianggles)] = np.nan
```

[image: contour plot with concave hole]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I figured the logic based on the line equation would be needed but the way you provided the general convey solution is exactly what I needed.